# How much should data be split up?

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm currently setting up a database with microsoft access.
The main goal is to re-setup a huge inventory in a well structured manner.
The current inventory is full with duplication and redundancy, which I'm trying to reduce with access. My question now is, how much the data should be splitted up into it's smallest, logic parts.

The list includes a lot of different data, I pretty much broke it down already, let me give you an overview:

[image: E/R-Diagram]

For me, it seems that I could split up the different attributes of a room into separate tables because each key shows up multiple times. For example, each room has a category (exp.: bureau) and a definition (exp.: conference room) and of course there are multiple rooms with the same category / definition.

Question is, does it make sense to split this into isolated tables? It feels like I am splitting this up way too much.

Comment: As a hint, you may read about _normalization_.  You should find some information out there, and you may relate it to your current database.

Comment: Normalize until hurts, denormalize until it works. It is a balancing act between normalization and ease of data entry/output.

Comment: you should make a E/R diagram and post it. That will help you and us to better visualize your data modeling.

Answer (score 1):

Your base data tables are:
Employees, Teams, Departments, Floors, Rooms, Workstations, Equipment.

Then you need lookup tables for things like: Employee_Gender or Room_Size (anything where you have to select from a fixed set of values).

Depending on how things work, Floors may be better used as a lookup table too by assigning teams directly to rooms rather than floors.

Also do not directly link Rooms and Devices. The link through Workstations is enough, unless you have devices assigned to rooms that do not belong to any workstation. Even then I would just create virtual workstation entries rather than have my table links loop.

If it is possible (ever) to have a team with employees from different departments, that part also needs to be different (employees assigned directly to departments and also independently to teams rather than being assigned to departments through their assignment to a team). In that case Team is also a lookup table rather than a main data table.

Answer (score 0):

`Size` is just a value and should be stored as value in `Room`, not as foreign key. You can have a lookup table for Sizes, if they are standardized, just to make data entry easier, but this is not useful as a relation.

`Room definition` is also a lookup table. But names can change, so I would go with foreign key here (from `Room`). But you can also store the definition name directly, if it helps make your life easier.

The rest is straightforward:

Room -> Floor
Device -> Room

There is no n:m relation needing a connector table here.